# What graph fulfills these properties?

Tags: graphing-functions

I need to think of a function for a graph which reflects in the x axis and has a horizontal asymptote at y=0.
I have a hunch it is going to involve a modulus of x but cant quite put my finger on it.
Thanks.

Comment: You might try $f(x)=0$

Answer (score 0):

You can use $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$.

Comment: Is that not reflected in the Y axis?

Comment: @user440380: Sorry I could not figure out the meaning of "reflected in". Switch axis and use $x=e^{-|y|}$.